# Are questions on fly tying (making fly fishing flies) on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Fly tying – the act of crafting the flies used when fly fishing – is an important part of fly fishing for many who partake in that activity. However, it is not done outdoors and is, in a sense, about manufacturing and handicraft. I think that we would benefit from accepting such questions if we want to enlarge the fishing community within the site, but I'm not sure about our policy regarding things that are not necessarily 'outdoor activities.' Should we allow and perhaps even seed some of these questions when trying to attract more fishing aficionados?

Comment: http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/43/18

Comment: @Kevin I understand that fishing is on-topic, but I'm asking about fly tying, which is the act of crafting flies that are used in fly fishing. It is not clear from the discussion that you linked to if this is on topic, mainly by the reasons that I mentioned above.

Comment: I see, I wasn't familiar with the term. I think it would be fine; there's only one way to find out.

Comment: Fly tying (I would suggest) **is** fishing, which (as kevin has pointed) out has already been discussed, so this seems perfectly on topic to me.

Comment: replace tying with fishing....not awake this am obviously

Comment: definitely on topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion this is very much OK and on topic. You can compare it to some gear questions we get on other outdoor topics:

- [How to take care of steel crampons?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5276/how-to-take-care-of-steel-crampons)
- [What does it need to maintain clothes including membranes](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4987/what-does-it-need-to-maintain-clothes-including-membranes)
- [How to do maintenance for a trekking backpack?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5716/how-to-do-maintenance-for-a-trekking-backpack)
- [Best technique to sharpen a knife using a whetstone?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/7285/best-technique-to-sharpen-a-knife-using-a-whetstone)
- [Taking care of hiking backpack](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1346/taking-care-of-hiking-backpack)
- [How do I take care of Gore-Tex boots?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/54/how-do-i-take-care-of-gore-tex-boots)
- [How to wash hiking boots](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4968/how-to-wash-hiking-boots)
- [How to store a bow?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/8505/how-to-store-a-bow)

We even have tags for [maintenance](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance) and [equipment-care](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment-care). Fly tying may fit in those tags too. I am not sure about that, but at least it fits well to the site I think!